# Assign content of DIR to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I wrote the following cmd

```
DIR /B "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
```

which returns the following single folder which exists at that dir location

```
4jktnrk2.default
```

I wish to store ***4jktnrk2.default*** in a variable.

I tried the following

```
SET A=DIR /B "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
```

and

```
SET A="DIR /B %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"
```

However neither of these work.

I also think its best to **not** use a **FOR** loop as there is only One folder in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "dir_c="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('DIR /B "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"') do (
    if "!dir_c!" equ "" (
        set "dir_c=%%~a"
    ) else (
        set "dir_c=!dir_c!;%%~a"
    )
)
echo %dir_c%
```

You have no other option but to use `FOR /F`.There's no unix style for assigning the result of command to variable in batch.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me. I think that the *real* goal of this request is to "Get a single folder in a variable". The code segment below do that:

```
for /D %%a in ("%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*") do set "A=%%a"
```

The *natural* way of process folders in a Batch file is via `for /D` command (the same way than the natural way to process files is via plain `for` command). The `for /F ... in ('dir /B ...` command is a less efficient method that is used just when `for` or `for /D` commands don't provide the required results.

Answer (score 1):

You really should use FOR /D or FOR /F as Aacini and npocmaka have suggested.

If you insist that you don't want to use FOR, then you will have to resort to a temporary file:

```
dir /b "%appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" >folder.tmp
set /p "a=" <folder.tmp
del folder.tmp
```